# Building docker container with perl and R modules

Tags: r, perl, docker, containers

I have bash, perl and R scripts that I would like to build docker container for; they are a small pipeline (the bash runs the others in correct order). The R and perl scripts require some modules. Besides using the pipeline, I would like to practice creating docker containers, as I am a beginner in the field of containers.

However, I am stuck at the beginning, and am wondering if there are other options for base images aside from ubuntu. As far as I know, it takes about ~190Mb, and I feel it is a bit overkill for the task. Do you have any idea how could I build it to be more lightweight?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Have a look at alpine linux

Comment: It is always better to implement a solution, before optimizing it. Therefore, if you are comfortable with Ubuntu, go ahead and collect your required modules and install Perl, GNU R, and all requirements.

Comment: A most basic R container -- such as [r-base](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/) which I co-maintain as part of the [Rocker Project](https://www.rocker-project.org/) -- is already 700mb give or take.  You then need to add some more Perl and R modules.  So Alpine is IMHO a distraction.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I didn't know that R is so big. In this situation it really doesn't make sense to perhaps save some 10s of MB and on the other side have Alpine potentially mess up what runs just fine on Debian

Comment: Thanks for help, so I won't be able to leave out ubuntu.